# Apache Storm：Will the late tuple be ack or fail?

Tags: apache-storm

I have the following information in my log.

**Q1:**  Does this cause spout to receive failed messages? Causes the tuple tree to which this tuple belongs to fail?

**Q2：** Why are these late tuples late for a few minutes, but the complete latency shown in the UI is still a few hundred milliseconds?

**Q3：** There is no late tupe when the input rate is 10 tuples/s, but it will appear in large numbers when it is increased to 100 tuples/s, so it will not work properly. What should I do to solve this problem?

```
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=project, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-9-count_bolt-executor[53 53] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=free, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=full, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-9-count_bolt-executor[53 53] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=almost, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=for, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-9-count_bolt-executor[53 53] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=whatsoever., timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=project, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=for, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=others., timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
2018-11-26 09:23:55.056 o.a.s.t.WindowedBoltExecutor Thread-11-count_bolt-executor[40 40] [INFO] Received a late tuple {word=project, timestamp=1543194524005} with ts 1543194524005. This will not be processed.
```

**Update:**

My topology：KafkaSpout--->SpilitBolt--->EventTimeWindowCountBolt--->KafkaSink

Storm Version：1.2.1

CountBolt：

```
 builder.setBolt("count_bolt", new CountBlot()
                .withTumblingWindow(new Duration(time_windowsize, TimeUnit.SECONDS))   //3s
                .withLag (new Duration(time_windowlag, TimeUnit.SECONDS))  // 1s
                .withTimestampField("timestamp")
                , parallelism)
                .fieldsGrouping("split_bolt", new Fields("word"));
```

Comment: By looking at the source code, it is found that the late tuple will be acked. `if (lateTupleStream != null) {
                     windowedOutputCollector.emit(lateTupleStream, input, new Values(input));
                 } else {
                     LOG.info("Received a late tuple {} with ts {}. This will not be processed.", input, ts);
                 }
                 windowedOutputCollector.ack(input);`                                    
  Why is there a lot of failed messages in my UI spout? There are only a lot of late tuple messages in the spout log.

Comment: You should provide some more details, like the topology you are ran, the storm version...